# The save method of PDDocument will cause 'java heap space' when the server saves large files

Tags: java, pdfbox

code:

```
File file = new File(filePath);

    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file, password, MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());

            if (null == doc) {

                return false;
            }
            doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);

            File files = new File(pdfPath);

            doc.save(files);

            doc.close();
```

error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyof(Arrays.java:3236)
[image]

There is no problem saving files locally, but the server will. The server's memory space is larger than that of the machine

Comment: where is this exception thrown from?

Comment: `doc.save(files);`,there

Comment: Did you try using the save to output stream?

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: I tried the output stream method, but the same result.pdfbox---2.0.20

Comment: The current version is 2.0.24. If it still doesn't work, please share your file, and mention what -Xmx setting you have.

Comment: Thanks,it still doesn't work,now the server's memory is 4gb, IDEA's memory setting is -Xms128m -Xmx2034m, my file (http://filedropper.com/wd8BIXvF), and finally I updated the error that appeared

Comment: The stack trace seems to indicate that the exception is *not* thrown during `doc.save(files)` but actually already during `PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file, password, MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly())`. It looks like your service simply requires more memory. As soon as PDFBox 3.0 is published, you should try updating as loading on demand is implemented there.

Comment: In fact, `doc.save(files)` did have an exception before, but now there is also an exception where the document is loaded.Thanks,it seems that there is no better way now